# Manually packaging an apk file

Tags: android, apk

Is there a way to manually repackage an apk (that will successfully run on a real device). While we can use any zip tool to unpack our apk files, the reverse is not possible (due to some app signing issues and such ) so I'm wondering how to go about doing this. I don't want to build an apk (which would involve compling Java classes , resources etc). I just want to be able to create an apk file ( that will run on a device) manually (command line is ok), provided that I already have all the necessary files.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, there are command line tools for signing and aligning APK's.  See the docs and existing questions here.

Comment: Thank you but I was hoping that someone would point me to a procedure to do this (i.e. the steps necessary to do this

Comment: I found the answer. You can use keytool (for signing your apk ) and zipalign (for aligning it)